# Error on add external css in augular-cli.json file from AWS s3 or CDN

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, angular-cli

I want to include css file from s3 but project failed to compile

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/WebstormProjects/ra_management_frontend/src/http:/myurl/ra-management/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

and below I am including an external link in angular-cli.json file

```
 "styles": [
    "http://myurl/ra-management/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
   "./styles/main.scss"

 ],
 "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

 ],
```

Thanks in advance.any help or guideline will be appreciate a lot

Comment: I think for non local resources like CDN s jst add to the index.html

Comment: No need to add to angular-cli.json